# List of today's updated files in VSS

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, checkin

I am using this command and this does nothing, not even an error message, I am confused where does the result go and where can I check it?

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe> ss.exe history $/myproject -Vd24/10/13~23/10/13 -R
```

I have also set the environment variable i.e. `set ssdir` which is working fine.

I have to get the list of files (just file names) which are checkedin (modified) today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to get the list of files (just file names) which are checkedin
>   (modified) today.

You can Right-click on the directory in VSS Explorer and choose View History: you can add date filters to the search